# How to get running @font-face with webpack?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, font-face, webpack-2

I can't get @font-face working with webpack. I am working with vuejs framework. This is an error I am getting. I tried with url-loader, and with file-loader but couldn't solve it. I am also new at both, webpack and vue, so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

[image]

On next img you can see my folder structure and webpack config.

[image]

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato-Light';
    src: url('../../fonts/Lato-Light/Lato-Light.eot');
    src: url('../../fonts/Lato-Light/Lato-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded- 
opentype'),
    url('../../fonts/Lato-Light/Lato-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../fonts/Lato-Light/Lato-Light.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../fonts/Lato-Light/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../../fonts/Lato-Light/Lato-Light.svg#Lato-Light') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

All @font-face is placed in index.scss inside typography folder, and everything is imported in index.scss inside common folder.

Comment: try file-loader instead, and `/\.(woof2?|eot|ttf|otf)$/`only.

Comment: If the `@font-face`s are in the typography folder I believe you have too few dots in the urls, try `url('../../../fonts/Lato-Light/Lato-Light.eot')` :)

Comment: @MagnusBuvarp i fixed it but still getting same error

Comment: @MatheusSilva it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. So firstly I setup configuration like this and put in the rules collection:

```
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
  }
```

After that I was getting error that my path is not working. That is cause my font url paths weren't relative to my root scss file. They were relative to the scss file were they used. Sass/libsass does not provide url rewriting, so all linked assets must be relative to the output. I fixed this using resolve-url-loader.

[sass-loader problems-with-url](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url)

[resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader)

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'resolve-url-loader'
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'resolve-url-loader',
      'sass-loader?sourceMap'
    ],
  }
```

And if you are using vue-loader you need also this:

```
'scss': [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'resolve-url-loader',
          'sass-loader?sourceMap',
          {
```

Comment: That tripped me that sass pathing wasn't properly addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Move your file-loader options to `rules` collection instead of `loaders`, it was deprecated and seems to have been overwritten by `rules` collection.